# How does "/f179" relate to twitter's little bird icon?

Tags: html, css, twitter, frontend

If I inspect on the little bird icon on twitter.com I see that its css has `content: "/f179"`. Is this for twitter's icon? Is this for a special font with lots of special characters including twitter's icon?

Comment: Probably part of what is called an *SVG Font*. Used for icons/symbols for better control and usability.

Comment: They using unicodes and using (own) special fonts. Like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io) do.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Add above link in head section of page and following code use for twitter icon on your page..

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

They turn SVG icons into a font, and use unicode to stand for it. This kind of font can be made by yourself in iconmoon or simply using font-awesome.